# Interactions with other application

Tags: c++, interaction

I'm a learning c++, I want to know that how programs are made that can interact with other application in windows.By interaction I mean like clicking a button, giving keyboard input, changing settings of that application, changing options or even editing or creating files.How can I make such Programs in C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you interact with other applications depends on your OS. If e.g your application runs on windows you have to use the Win32 API. The Win32 API are functions provided by the OS allowing you to interact not just with other applications but also with the OS itself, e.g to set up windows or to open files.

Win32 provides a messaging system. Every application has a message loop and accepts messages from the OS (e.g about mouse clicks) but can also receive messsages from other applications. The receiver cant decide whether the message comes from the OS or from another process.

To e.g change the title, you have to send the other application a [WM_SETTEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632644%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message using the [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Directly interacting with another application (changing its values, not just modifying the GUI) is just possible, if the application provides some kind of interface. These could be a network connection, named pipes, shared memory or some module/plugin loading mechanism (through dlls). Otherwise its not possible (easily).

For UNIX based OS an API called [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) exists providing similiar functionality as Win32.

Comment: Ok, there's win32 is there something other than win32 for doing same things in windows.For GUIs part I found win32 difficult so I'm currently learning Qt which is a lot easier than win32.Is there is a way I can intergrate Qt(for gui) and win32 for interaction if yes how

Comment: @TheExperimenter Yes, simply by including it? Qt doesnt use anything else than Win32 under the hood. Why should they interfer with each other? And including windows.h doesnt mean that you must use it for your GUI o.O